# Oracle SQL show null value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do the following query:

```
SELECT column1,column2,column3
FROM tablename
WHERE
column1 IN
('string1','string2','string3','string4')
AND column2='some_value';
```

The results show only:
String1, string2,string3 because string4 does not have an equivalent some_value in column2.

How can I show all 4 values with the 4th showing as null like:

```
Column1|column2|column3
+----------------------+
|string1 value  value  |
|string2 value  value  |
|string3 value  value  |
|string4 null   null   |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: ... AND (column2='some value' OR column2 is null)

Comment: alternatively ... AND (nvl(column2, 'some value') = 'some value')

Comment: You may need to be more specific about your intent.  What is your spec?  What is the rule that makes it that row #4 should be returned as well?  The current answers are making educated guesses, but they are still only guesses unless you explicitly state the logic you want to apply to each row.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column1,column2,column3
FROM tablename
WHERE
column1 IN
('string1','string2','string3','string4')
AND column2='some_value'
OR (column2 is null or column3 is null);
```

You should say`column2 is null` at the end. as it doesn't correspond to your `where` condition.

Comment: It's hard to know if the query is correct because I'm not even sure what OP is actually looking for. However, I suspect you didn't mean to code the query such that nulls in `column2` or `column3` cause the row to return *regardless* of the value in `column1`. You may be missing an extra set of brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Add OR

```
SELECT column1,column2,column3
FROM tablename
WHERE
    column1 IN ('string1','string2','string3','string4')
AND (
        column2='some_value'
     OR column2 is null
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the treatment is diferent, if value of column2 is only diferent from "some value" (parameter) return all lines. 
- In this case: 
 - column2 with diferent value from parameter will be returned with empty value on column2 and column3.
 - column2 with null value will be returned

SELECT column1, CASE WHEN column2 = 'some value' THEN COLUMN2 ELSE NULL END column2, CASE WHEN column2 = 'some value' THEN column3 ELSE NULL END column3
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE
column1 IN
('string1','string2','string3','string4')
AND (column2='value' OR column2 = COLUMN2 OR column2 IS null);